# How & where to set up DB Server and communicate with iPhone

Tags: hosting, database, iphone

I'm working on iPhone app that will let users upload/download photos to/from a DB server along with some data associated with each photo.

While I do have experience with iPhone programing, I do not have much experience with DB and server side programing.

Does anyone have any tips on what would be the easiest way to set up DB server and handle requests and responses coming from the iPhone. This server may be potentially required to handle large amount of traffic and preserve data integrity. Several iPhone users might be attempting to upload and modify data associated with each photo at the same time.

I'm thinking of opening a hosted server account so I don't have to purchase hardware and run it from home. Any tips on a company that provides quality and affordable server and DB hosting would be much appreciated.

Thx,
-Goran

Comment: this is more stackoverflow.com question. some hint - use universal firewall traversal protocol aka http to talk to some servlet-like code on the server that will write/read things from db.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of hosting providers out there.  Just hit google, and you'll get a ton of options.

As for how to do this, the basics are that you'll want to have a web method on the web server that takes in the requests with the file and the info about the file.

That should then safe the file to the hard drive on a file server, then save the meta data to the database, including a pointer to the file on the file server.

If you try and store the file in your database, your database will become very large and hard to manage very quickly and performance will suffer greatly.

You could very easily put this onto a computer of machines in the cloud (Amazon, Azure, etc).